# Pygame application not opening a png

Tags: python, pygame

For some reason, my python program will not open my file in a directory called `imgs` in which I have a png file that I wish it to display when it runs.

The `imgs` directory is in the same location as my python program on my C drive. I have made sure that I am entering the correct names and that there is no / before imgs

It always pops up with the message

```
pygame.error: Couldn't open imgs/tileGrass1
```

`tileGrass1` being the png

Any suggestions on how to fix this??

Comment: can u share ur code

Comment: Are you asking about PyCharm or Python? It looks like you running into a runtime error in a python program (_not_ in PyCharm) due to the file `imgs/tileGrass1` not existing. Are you sure this file exists under the path you specified, and that it doesn't have a file extension such as `.png`?

Comment: Do note that your question currently is not visible to many users since you did not include a language tag. It looks like you meant to tag this question `python`, the language,  rather than `pycharm`, which is an ide.

Comment: As others have suggested, the issue is likely due to correct filenames and paths. You could try printing the results of `os.listdir("imgs")` to see the names of the files that are in that directory from Python's perspective. Also you may find taking the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and reading about [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) useful.

Answer (score 0):

Few checks to ensure a pygame program is running well

1. Ensure You Initialize the pygame library at the beginning of your code

   pygame.init()
2. Ensure Path to your image is correct and that the image exists. Check that the extension is correct (png, jpg, jpeg, etc)
   It would also be useful if you share the code to your program so that the exact error is easily noted